# Erro no decode e convert_from do Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Alguém já passou pelo problema do Postgres dar erro no decode base64?
Tenho a seguinte chamada que informa **[Err] ERRO:  fim de sequência é inválido**

```
convert_from(decode('YnJhc2lsc2VtbGVp', 'base64'), 'UTF8')
```

Lembrando que onde tenho **'YnJhc2lsc2VtbGVp'** estou usando um variavel, então fica assim

```
convert_from(decode(variavel, 'base64'), 'UTF8')
```

Comment: Situação resolvida. Efetuei um conversão do campo para o tipo TEXT e resolveu.

Comment: Provavelmente faltou o `==` no final da sequência: `convert_from(decode('YnJhc2lsc2VtbGVp==', 'base64'), 'UTF8')`

Comment: @JorgeKania Você fala sobre uma tal `variavel` mas não menciona o tipo e nem o conteúdo dela. Essas informações são **cruciais** para o entendimento e a explicação da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente `variavel` contém uma string `base64` malformada.

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT convert_from(decode('aeiou', 'base64'), 'UTF8');
```

Saída:

```
ERROR:  invalid base64 end sequence
HINT:  Input data is missing padding, is truncated, or is otherwise corrupted.
SQL state: 22023
```

Isso se dá pois `aeiou` não se trata de uma string `base64` válida e não pode ser decodificada adequadamente pelo Postgres.

Um exemplo prático seria:

Codificando texto para `base64`:

```
SELECT encode('Olá Mundo!', 'base64')
```

Saída:

```
|           encode |
|------------------|
| T2zDoSBNdW5kbyE= |
```

Decodificando `base64` para texto:

```
SELECT convert_from(decode('T2zDoSBNdW5kbyE=', 'base64'), 'UTF8');
```

Saída:

```
| convert_from |
|--------------|
|   Olá Mundo! |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/90979